# R: Correcting the year of a date in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with observations and the dates at which they were made. The dates are read from a csv file, but only include month and day. R assumes that they are all from 2016. I know that the dates are in order from most to least recent, so how would I go about adding on the correct years?

The inputs are in order from most to least recent.

```
Input            Output
1/1              1/1/2016
12/1             12/1/2015
11/1             11/1/2015
1/1              1/1/2015
12/1             12/1/2014
1/1              1/1/2014
12/1             12/1/2013
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you want to change only `12/03` with 2015?

Comment: Hi akrun, there are many more dates. I was just trying to explain myself. Thanks! I could go from 12/03 to 1/01 then to 11/11 and 11/11 should be in 2014

Comment: In that case, the explanation is not clear

Comment: It would be better if you show a bunch of dates and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is ordered as showed in the OP's post, we can extract the month part from the initial `vector` ('v1') using `sub`, convert to numeric, get the difference of adjacent elements, check whether it is greater than 0, `cumsum` the logical `vector`, use that grouping index to pass the year values, finally `paste` it with the initial vector.

```
v2 <- paste(v1, c(2016:2013)[cumsum(c(TRUE,
          diff(as.numeric(sub("/.*", "", v1))) > 0))], sep="/")
```

If we need to convert to 'Date' class, use `as.Date` with the correct `format`.

```
as.Date(v2, "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "2016-01-01" "2015-12-01" "2015-11-01" "2015-01-01" "2014-12-01"
#[6] "2014-01-01" "2013-12-01"
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you! Should the dates need to go past 2013, would changing 2013 to 2010 work?

Comment: @jw123456  Yes, you can use from 2016:1800 or so, it will only take the values based on the numeric index

Comment: Thank you for your help!